# DatePickerDialog in arabic language

Tags: android, datepicker

I have an application in Arabic and I want to view the DatePickerDialog in Arabic.

I have tried setting "Locale" but that didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer is to change the "Locale" of the whole app to "ar"
At your starting activity set your application Locale to "ar" by below code and all views and dialogs will be switched to Arabic.

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config =
            getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    createConfigurationContext(config);
```