# How to display months and days in Vietnamese in DatePickerDialog?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

How to display months and days in Vietnamese in DatePickerDialog for Android and DatePicker in IOS when the app language to Vietnamese in Xamarin forms

**Android:**

```
protected override DatePickerDialog CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            pickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context, (o, e) =>
            {
                datePicker.Date = e.Date;
                ((IElementController)datePicker).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
            }, year, month, day);

            //ok
            pickerDialog.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive, AppResources.AlertDismiss, OnDone);

            //cancel
            pickerDialog.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative, AppResources.PickerCancelText, OnCancel);

            return pickerDialog;
        }
```

**IOS:** suggest me how to do in IOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly , do you want to show English formatting for the DatePicker?

If so you can modify the `Locale` for the datepicker  in custom renderer .

### iOS Solution

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DatePicker), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.iOS
{
    class MyRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
          
            if(Control != null)
            {
                UIDatePicker picker = Control.InputView as UIDatePicker;
                picker.Locale = new NSLocale("us");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

---

If you want the `Datepicker` only display `month` and `day` for selecting item , it could be a little complex , because iOS does not provide the option/mode to achieve that , you need to create a view and controller that implement the UIPickerViewDelegate and create your own .

Refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/412754/8187800.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24971192/8187800.

---

### Android Solution

Add the following code into OnCreate in `MainActivity` class .

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            //this code 
            Locale locale = Locale.Us;
            Locale.SetDefault(Locale.Category.Format, locale);
            Configuration config = this.Resources.Configuration;
            config.SetLocale(locale);
            CreateConfigurationContext(config);
                
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

#### Before

[image]

###After

[image]

Refer to

[DatePickerDialog in arabic language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266842/datepickerdialog-in-arabic-language)

[Set Android DatePicker title language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871800/set-android-datepicker-title-language)

Comment: So what you want is to display the English style ?

Comment: I  asked Vice versa English to Vietnamese. But Thanks For IOS it works.  I asked for both Android and IOS. For Android Please suggest me?

Comment: Is it possible to change at runtime if I switch language from English to Vietnamese and Vietnamese to English in app. Not the mobile language.

Comment: Yes , just use messaging center to call the code in specific platform project.