# AM/PM showing in different language in iOS

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a time picker basically the user can select time with it. It's perfectly displaying in Android. But, am/pm is displaying in different language in iOS. Any idea why it is happening ?

**Code**

```
                               <TimePicker x:Name="time"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                Format="hh:mm tt"
                                TextColor="{StaticResource TitleColor}"
                                Focused="time_Focused"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>


time.Time = new TimeSpan(07, 30, 00);
```

[image: View]

Comment: What locale is in use on the iOS device

Answer (score 1):

I know in just regular c# I would do something like this: date1.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) but I don't know how to add culture information in xaml code.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can check if the language supports English.
2. You can use Custom Renderer to override it.

   This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69524861/how-to-display-months-and-days-in-vietnamese-in-datepickerdialog) introduces the method of rewriting. You can refer to the specific method inside.