# AM/PM in Hindi in TimePicker Label on iOS device

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Time picker label is displaying the selected time AM/PM in hindi instead of english.
But it is displaying in english in the selecter section
As can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFcI4.png).
Device Language **English** and
Device Region **India**

I know this is a repetation of the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71405914/am-pm-showing-in-different-language-in-ios) question, but there was no answer to that there but a link to a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69524861/how-to-display-months-and-days-in-vietnamese-in-datepickerdialog). But still no changes on using this solution also.
I can't add comments in that questions to clarify because of my Reputation Points :(
Heres the TimePicker xaml snippet:

```
<TimePicker Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="startTimePicker" Format="hh:mm tt"
                                            PropertyChanged="OnTimePickerPropertyChanged" FontSize="Small"
                                            Focused="startTimePicker_Focused"
                                            Unfocused="startTimePicker_Unfocused"
                                            />
```

and my CustomRenderer implementation according to the second answer:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(TimePicker),typeof(CustomTimePicker))]
namespace TP_PlusTwo.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class CustomTimePicker:TimePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Red;//Testing
                var picker = Control.InputView as UIDatePicker;
                picker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
                picker.Locale = new Foundation.NSLocale("en_US");//Chat-GPT
                //picker.Locale = new Foundation.NSLocale("us");//StackOverflow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the language to others too but no success.
Only when i change the device Region from India to United States the Label starts showing correct AM/PM (still the locale setting in CUstom Renderer is not working).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your App.xaml.cs for the Xamarin forms shared project

```
public App()
{
 //add it in the constructor
 var netLanguage = "en";
 CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(netLanguage);
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
}
```

This code will set the culture globally in your app and avoid any confusion in datetime picking or parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [current culture (localization)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-8.0) on application level (app localization).

For iOS, you can set it in the **AppDelegate.cs** file override the `FinishedLaunching` method like below:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    this.SetLocale();
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}

private void SetLocale()
{
    CultureInfo englishCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = englishCultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = englishCultureInfo;
}
```